# count the dictionary keys in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
[{('white', 'man'): 114},
 {('white', 'woman'): 91},
 {('red', 'man'): 114},
 {('red', 'woman'): 114},
 {('blu', 'man'): 114},
 {('blu', 'woman'): 114}]
```

For this list of dicts I would need to count the the items of the `dict.keys`, namely the `n`. Occurrence of `[k, kk for k, kk in dict.keys()]`.

So in the example the result will look like: `white = 2`, `man = 3`, `red = 2`, `woman = 3`, `blu = 2`.

I tried the `[len(k), len(kk) for k, kk in dict.keys())]`, but it gives the length of word, not it count.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

msgs = [{('white', 'man'): 114}, {('white', 'woman'): 91}, {('red', 'man'): 114}, {('red', 'woman'): 114}, {('blu', 'man'): 114}, {('blu', 'woman'): 114}]

Counter(word for msg in msgs for words in msg for word in words)
```

returns

```
Counter({'woman': 3, 'man': 3, 'blu': 2, 'white': 2, 'red': 2})
```

which you can read as a dict

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this ?

```
dictionaries = [{('white', 'man'): 114},
{('white', 'woman'): 91},
{('red', 'man'): 114},
{('red', 'woman'): 114},
{('blu', 'man'): 114},
{('blu', 'woman'): 114}]
```

With the help of functions;

```
def find_key_count(key, lst):
    return sum([dic.keys()[0].count(key) for dic in lst])

print find_key_count("white", dictionaries)
```

returns

```
2
```

No need to take dictionaries as an argument if you have a single data, like so;

```
def find_key_count(key):
    return sum([dic.keys()[0].count(key) for dic in dictionaries])

print find_key_count("man")
```

prints

```
3
```